# Best way to create a visual route map using C# or python based off of MAC addresses

Tags: c#, python, sorting

This is more of recommendation or better approach question. The router has an output for a command that lists of MAC addresses that are put into 2 columns. Example:

```
Router MAC 11:11:11:00:00:00

Column1                Column 2  
00:00:00:11:11:11 via 00:00:00:11:11:11
00:00:00:22:22:22 via 00:00:00:11:11:11
00:00:00:33:33:33 via 00:00:00:33:33:33
00:00:00:44:44:44 via 00:00:00:22:22:22
```

If column 1 and column 2 mac addresses match it is considered a direct connection to the router.
so in the example above the second device 00:00:00:22:22:22 is using a HOP to the router. The HOP device is 00:00:00:11:11:11

There can be as many as 5 HOP maybe even more.

From the data above I was going to create a table by sorting, matching and comparing. Once done go back through and match again thus creating a map route table. It would update every 1 minute.

Any recommendation in C# or python on how to create this?

output would look something like below and a visual map if possible with MAC of the router in middle and line branching off for direct connects. hops would branch of those and so on.

```
Column 1 direct connect         1 HOP                  2 HOPS
00:00:00:11:11:11               00:00:00:22:22:22      00:00:00:44:44:44
00:00:00:33:33:33
```

Comment: `What is the best way to do something` tends to be more of an opinion-based question which is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Would it be better for me to simply ask what tools in C# or python would help me accomplish, what I want? I know I can create something to get the desired output shown but is there any tool that can help me with creating the visual map I descibed?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to get a good list of things that may be off-topic. Asking for recommendations for tools/resources/etc. is also off-topic for this. It would be best for you to attempt what you mentioned, and if you get stuck, then come here to ask how you may be able to proceed and what is wrong with what you've tried. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a language recommendation, I'd say python, just because it's string manipulation is much more user friendly, but, for ease of creating the 'visual' map, I'd probably say go with c# as the api for using windows forms can be pretty straightforward.

But if you're looking for me to just write the code for you, I won't do the whole thing, but here's the basics of what you need to do to solve it yourself:

1. Look for the pattern in the input data to your problem, in this case the table of addresses, use this to determine how you want to iterate over the data.
2. Ask yourself how to store the data to make it easier to display to the screen, my recommendation would be dictionary.
3. Determine how to print the said dictionary or other datastructure out to the screen